# Solr: stop words entirely stop the search, should just be disregarded

Tags: solr, ckan, stop-words

I have datasets in CKAN that have Titles like "Application for funding". If a search on "Application for funding" is entered, the results are returned. But if "Application for" is entered, zero results are returned. Is there a way to make it so stop words are disregarded but the other words are still used for search? "Application for" should search as though just "Application" was entered. What would the configuration be for that? It's just not clear what combination of configuration settings will accomplish this.

I didn't try a whole lot of tinkering with the SOLR configuration for fear of breaking it in a significant way, I'm hoping someone will know what specific setting or parameter is causing this. Is there a proper way to configure StopFilterFactory so that stop words are "ignored" while the words in the query that are NOT stop words "pass through"?

Comment: What you're asking for is the default behavior. What is the field type you're seeing this behavior on, and what is your actual query? Are you querying `field:"Application for"`, or are you searching `Application for` with dismax and `qf`?

Comment: Thanks Mats: I'll say.... I don't know, exactly. I wonder if CKAN ships with a configuration file template that isn't configured as "default". It's not the most urgent thing I'm trying to fix I'll look into it after some of my other issues are resolved.